# How to access Media files (such as images/video) present on a USB stick connected to a device?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-external-storage, usb-drive

I am building a File explorer kind of app for Android, which shows a categorized view of all files present in internal and external storage(s). For example to list all Video files present on device's storage, I applied the following code:

```
private void loadVideos()
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE;
        int data,folder,id,thumb,title,duration;

        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,null,null, orderBy);

        id      = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
        thumb   = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA);
        title   = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
        duration= cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long length = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(duration)) / 1000;
            long minutes = length / 60;
            long seconds = length % 60;

            items.add(new VideoItem(cursor.getString(title),cursor.getString(thumb),cursor.getString(id),properFormat(minutes)+":"+properFormat(seconds)));

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Everything works fine, except for when I attach a USB device. In which case it shows only those videos present on device, and doesn't show video files from the USB device.

Things that I have already checked:

> 1) Permissions for external storage is granted.
>      2) USB device is successfully mounted because it shows up in Settings as well as other apps such as MX Player shows video files from USB device.

I also have doubt regarding the Uri which currently is **MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI**.

But according to the name it feels like, it should have done the trick, although its clearly not working for external devices? Can anyone please guide me where I might be going wrong?
The goal is to show media files from Phone's internal storage, external storage (like Micro SD card) and from any external USB device (if attached). Thanks.

Comment: Does the Gallery app on your device show pictures from usb drive?

Comment: `1) Permissions for external storage is granted.` ?? What do you mean? You can only ask for permissions in manifest. Its the user who has to grant them. For Android 6+ you have to add code to ask the user to grant them. Runtime permissions. Well i do not know if this is causing your problem.

Comment: @greenapps like I said I am allowing the app required permission

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965209/use-the-device-filter-xml-resource-file-to-filter-usb-enumeration-results

Comment: @MartinZeitler aim is to scan media files on USB device not filter permission for certain USB devices :(

Comment: @Lincoln you won't scan anything, unless getting a handle to the device, in the first place... see my answer below.

Comment: @Lincoln Did you ever manage to scan media files on connected USB stick? I have been stuck at this for a few days and havent manage to come up with any solution? Is using Storage Access framework a good idea? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Comment: @kb_14 Not reliably, it worked on some types of devices/storage and sometimes not.

Comment: @Lincoln Could you share what you ended up using eventually?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that code now, it got scrapped for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UsbConstants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbConstants.html#USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE) states, that`USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE` would be `8` - therefore I'd say, that you need to reference `device_filter.xml` in the `Manifest.xml`, where the registering `Activity` is the one which shall handle the media.

```
<activity
...
>
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>

</activity>
```

and then filter in that referenced `device_filter.xml` for the device class `8`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>
    <usb-device class="8"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: So what this means that MediaStore won't be of help when it comes to fetching USB contents. Alright, but then will have to search for media files manually? Based upon extensions of files and recursively inside each folder? Won't that be intensive process?

Comment: @Lincoln have not yet tried this with mass-storage devices, but only with printers & scanners. one would (possibly) have to mount the file-system and then indeed search, or create a search index per media-type... looking at the AOSP sources of the `MediaStore` might provide valuable hints.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/ ...see the `MediaScanner` and the `MediaScannerClient`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to query for updated MediaStore, you have to make sure that MediaScanner finishes scanning and `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED` is received.